# Simple Logic to identify edges in matrix

Tags: algorithm, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am trying to calculate valid neighbour of a node

Array contains elements like `[2,8,3,0,1,4,7,6,5]`

Matrix:

```
          2 8 3
          0 1 4
          7 6 5
```

It's similar to 8 puzzle logic. In the above matrix, i can swap 0 with 2 or 1 or 7. i tried with -1,+1,-3,+3. But 0 can't be swapped with 3. so i can't use -1 or +1. Also i need to update the position in array. What is the logic to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only 3x3 you can hardcode the neighbour-list (if it was more complicated I would suggest writing a logic that computes it):

```
neighbour-map := {0:[1,3], 1:[0,2,4], 2:[1,4,5],...}
```

`0:[1,3]` means that the first item in the array (value=`2`) has neighbours on the indexes: 1,3 (values: `8` and `0`). etc.

If you need to deal with a larger "matrix", then you *should* compute the neighbors.
It'll be easier for you to move the input into a matrix (array of arrays) and then calculate it according to the list of "rules" that ak0053792 wrote below - but also handle all the "corner" cases (items that are on the upper-most line don't have a neighbor at y-1 for example).

Comment: it's dynamic. the above will goes up to 8x8 matrix. i can't hardcode this value. i need to check it during run time

Comment: @iPhoneGuy hint: you'll have to use modulo heavily

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic would be check if the array element from which we are swapping selected element is neighbouring element. This could be done by below algorithm

1) Locate the position of current element

2) Locate the position of the element from which swapping is done.

3) Check if the position of swapping element lies in range below from current element, so if the position of current element is x,y then swapping element must lie in :

```
1) x-1, y-1
2) x-1, y
3) x-1, y+1
4) x, y-1
5) x, y+1
6) x+1, y+1
7) x+1, y
8) x+1, y-1
```

Comment: He is using a flat array, this is not a matrix (you don't have two coordinates).

Comment: yes. i am using flat array. i can check logic with the above mentioned condition. but i need to update/swap objects in the flat array

Comment: Yes, true. But ideally, using 2D array seems more logical here.

Comment: i am using objective c to achieve this. But i started with a flat array which could be complicate my entire logic if i change it to 2d array.

Comment: @iPhoneGuy you can build a "translator" from 1d-array into 2d-array and back. That will be the easier part :)

Comment: @alfasin that would be easier and more logical.